# Trabajar el codigo abierto de tux paint

Tags: android-studio, compilar

quiero compilarlo primero en android estudio pero no he podido pueden explicarme el proceso pues se que debo instalar dependencias pero me sale que no encuentra el archivo glade.wrapper.properties y no corre muchas gracias.
me sale este error
Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:]. Build mode: ASSEMBLE. Tests: None.

Comment: Pero que quieres compilar, no vemos nada